# Docker networking not working with bridged host interfaces

Tags: networking, router, iptables, docker, bridge

Here's the setup: (docker host is in between to monitor traffic via ntopng)

```
   Router      <--->    Docker Host      <--->       PC
<192.168.1.1>         <192.168.1.20>            <192.168.1.30>
```

The docker host has 2 NICs (eth0 and eth1) bridged into br0, via files in `/etc/systemd`.

The bridge itself works fine, I can ping the internet and router from the Docker Host and PC, and the Docker Host and PC can ping each other, non docker web services are accessible as well.

What does not work, is accessing any Docker container ports from the PC, `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name web nginx` does not let the PC access the web server, it just hangs. I also cannot ping the PC from inside the container (but can ping the Router). `--net=host` does work though.

If I plug the PC into the router instead, then I can access it, just not when it's being bridged by the Docker Host. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip r` and `iptables-save` to your question?

Comment: `ip a` and `brctl show` might also be informative, as well as the contents of those `/etc/systemd` files that have set up the `br0` bridge. I suspect that docker's bridge is hooked up to whichever `eth` device is wired to the router, but not to the `eth` device wired to the PC.

Comment: Reset all `iptables` rules and re-installed docker and it seems to be ok now, thanks!